# How to delete an array attribute for all values in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, list

I want to return all users in JSON format except their passwords. To do so, I have done something like this

```js
try {
        const rawResults = await model.find(query).limit(limit).skip(startIndex)
        results.results = rawResults.forEach((v) => delete v.password)
    } catch (error) {
        results.error = error
    }
```

now when I am trying to console.log the result value, it always returns

```
{ next: null, results: undefined }
```

Please help me fix this issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, since this jumped out, the passwords *are* encrypted right?

Comment: [`map` might be useful here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) You can [deconstruct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) each object into a new array.

Comment: can you provide a sample input?

Comment: If you're not doing anything with the passwords in your code, better not fetch them in the first place. Your model.find() will probably have a parameter to state what you want (or want not) to retrieve. For example, if it were mongoose: `model.find(query, '-password')` should do the trick

Comment: @NickBailey Ya, It's encrypted using bcrypt.

Comment: @malarres That's it. I didn't know about this query. Thank yo so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ForEach modifies the original object.

If you don't need rawResults any more (hopefully, as passwords should be encrypted as [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4410674/nick-bailey) pointed out), you can use your code as follows:

```
try {
    const rawResults = await model.find(query).limit(limit).skip(startIndex)
    rawResults.forEach((v) => delete v.password)
    results.results = rawResults
} catch (error) {
    results.error = error
}
```

If you need separate RawResults and result objects you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of forEach:

```
try {
    const rawResults = await model.find(query).limit(limit).skip(startIndex)
    results.results = rawResults.map(({password, ...v}) => v)
} catch (error) {
    results.error = error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.forEach` returns `undefined`.

Just call `rawResults.forEach((v) => delete v.password)` without the `results.results =`  and your code will work.

Comment: yaaa, I got it now. Thank you so much